# How can i connect to remote server for CPU process time monitoring?

Tags: monitor

I want to connect to remote server to monitor the cpu process time when i run the stress test.
But it always failed, what can i do to successfully connect to remote server ?

Comment: Which OS? This will probably end up on serverfault or superuser. How are you trying to connect?

Comment: I use prefmon.msc to connect to remote server, but failed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, you can **ssh** into the remote server by knowing its hostname and ip as explained [here.](http://gssg-www.stanford.edu/public/ssh/SSHExamples.html)

You also require to know the root password of the remote server.
To check the CPU process time, memory ,etc during the stress test, you can use [**SeaLion**](http://www.sealion.com).
It allows you to monitor the output of commands like top, free -m,etc on a graphical inteface, thus everytime you perform your test, you wouldn't require to connect to the remote server.

There is also [**New Relic**](http://www.newrelic.com) which is extremely feature rich and provides many functionalities like graphing, etc.